# loading div before finishing all result data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm going sending data the Info page with ..$_get.. but I want when click ..a href=new.php?data=1.. to activate loading and Not all received data loading be enabled and after the completion information inside page new.php , loading deletion and .div id=result. is displayed or show information

new.php

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('a').click(function(){
                $('#result').hide();
                $('#main').html('<strong>loading...!</strong>;');
                success:function(){
                    $('#main').html('');
                    $('#result').show();
                }
            });
        });
        </script>
 <body>

<div id="main"></div>
<a href="new.php?data=1">test</a>
<div id="result">
 <?php
    if(isset($_GET['data'])){
        echo $_GET['data'];
    }
?>
</div>
```

when click a href= Enable loading then when Information was received, remove loading and put the information in div result displayed

Comment: What exactly is your question? It's unclear.

Comment: when click a href= Enable loading then when Information was received, remove loading and put the information in div result displayed

Comment: Pasting a portion of the question will not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a mistake, `click()` isn't an ajax call so I don't understand why you put a `success` callback, try to remove it because it made a syntax JS error for sure.

There is the solution :

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('a').click(function(event){
                $('#result').hide();
                $('#main').html('<strong>loading...!</strong>;');
            });
        });
    </script>
    <body>
        <div id="main"></div>
        <a href="new.php?data=1"></a>
        <div id="result">
        <?php
            if(isset($_GET['data'])){
                echo $_GET['data'];
            }
        ?>            
        </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: I do not want to use Ajax because the whole project is a page I send data with click  tag a to base-url and with (isset(get)) the same page will to re-read in

Comment: @user3445955 I fix my answer to match your question

Comment: With this command, so long as he continues to work loading not receive complete information after complete it is removed loading

Comment: Please look at the site later realized I wanted to http://holygod.ir/quran-fa-ayati.php?sura=1&verse=1&to=7

Comment: @user3445955 do you have any JS error ? Open the console (F12) then look at console panel